# Disable nested scrolling for a child Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Scrollable column, that has inside it another Scrollable column, and a MapView.

As the default behaviour of Compose is to allow Nested Scrolling, this makes it somewhat difficult to control these 2 children that can also consume gestures.

I want to make it so that when these children receive a pointer event, they handle it themselves, and never pass anything to the parent.

No unconsumed values or what so. As long as the pointer event is in their bounds, they consume it all.

How can I achieve that?

I've tried to look into NestedScrolling, but that gives more control over the parent, not the children.

And some search about Pointer Events lead me to one solution that disabled all gestures inside a child. But I want the child to consume the gestures and use them, not dispose of them.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Modifier.nestedScroll()` with a custom `NestedScrollConnection` object.

For example you can disable children scrolling by overriding onPreScroll

```
override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource) = available.copy(x = 0f)
```

Or disable parent scrolling :

```
override fun onPostScroll(
                consumed: Offset,
                available: Offset,
                source: NestedScrollSource
            ) = available.copy(x = 0f)
```

Comment: have been looking the solution for days, this works for me, thx!!

Comment: Hi, your answer is wrong as `NestedScrollConnection` is for parent compose. OP wants to consume all the events for a particular child compose and prevent the nested scrolling and rather wants the child to consume all scroll events

@DinoTw did this solution really work for you or your problem was different from OP's?